Android Studio Emulators not working working. How do I fix the error?
I am running Android Studio on a Mac running Catalina Version 10.15.7 (it is an older Mac!)
My emulators were running an older version of Android (6 I think). I upgraded one of them to Android 11. Now none of the emulators will start. I tried starting one from the terminal and here is the error:
$ /Users/dan/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd CT60_Android_Accelerated_x86
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-dan/emu-crash-34.2.13.db, detection is enabled for process: 1793
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.13.0 (build_id 11772612) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /Users/dan/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/
dyld: Symbol not found: _kCGColorSpaceITUR_2100_HLG
  Referenced from: /Users/dan/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt6WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.6.5.3.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 11.0)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
 in /Users/dan/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt6WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.6.5.3.dylib
[1795:78322:20240504,185340.401720:WARNING process_memory_mac.cc:93] mach_vm_read(0x7ffeece6a000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)
[1795:78322:20240504,185340.603087:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:235] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
Abort trap: 6

I tried creating a new emulator and get the same error. Any ideas how I can fix this?

try upgrading/reinstalling your android studio. It sounds like your dev tools are corrupt.

AFAIK Android Studio only needs MacOS 10.14 but the Qemu Emulator needs a newer MacOS. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find where I got this information from.

I installed an update to Android Studio...no joy. I uninstalled and reinstalled the app, including the library files. Still no joy.

same problem, using macOS catalina and latest andriod studio.did you find any solution to this ? same errors in the log

Android Emulator 34.2.13 is a bad version, which will cause crash when booting virtual device. I aslo suffered a lot from it. The versions before it don't have this bug.
Additionally, the version starts from 34.1.18 has the problem that initial window is too small.
So I directly downgrade to 33.1.24.
https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator

Downgrading the emulator from 35.x.x to 33.1.24 worked for me on Catalina 10.15.7

The symbol _kCGColorSpaceITUR_2100_HLG (related to color management) is required by a library within the Android emulator and the Android emulator library causing the issue was compiled for macOS 11 (Big Sur) or later.
Try to Downgrade Emulator or System Image. Worked for me!
